# Global inbox incompatible with no-images

Tags: support, user-interface, global-inbox

The Stack Exchange global inbox (at the top left of the title bar) doesn't have a no-image alternative.

Browsing the normal (non-mobile) site with images turned off on a slow connection, the link still works, but there is no text to tell you the link is there. If you have pending inbox messages the number in a red circle does show up.

I'm seeing this with Opera 11.50, on Windows 7.

[image]

Just to clarify the Stackexchange logo link image is missing, but the link still works. The stackexchange alt-text on the popup is present

Comment: The drop-down menu is using CSS sprites, not `img`. That's the problem. With CSS enabled, but no images, the text is still hidden (using `text-indent: -999em`) but the sprite is not shown.